# windows 10 vim 8.0 surround plugin not working

Tags: windows, vim, plugins, surround

I am on Windows 10 64 bit. and I installed surround plugin using vim-plug plugin manager. but it seems not working. I tried it with vim 7.4 it didn't work. I tried installed surround.vim plugin. it still not working. but the plugin NERDTree along with the vim-plug works! can't I use surround on windows 64 or some other version problem ?
here it is my .vimrc snippet screenshot, I tried :set surround. it says surround is not defined.
I also tried vundle and patheogen none of them works.why?
[image]

Comment: What makes you say Surround doesn't work? What are you trying to achieve with `:set surround`?

Comment: I followed the wiki page of surround.vim, Hello World, then cs"' , it won't change into "Hello World".

Comment: Read it again: `cs"'` changes `"Hello World"` into `'Hello World'` (double quotes to single quotes).

Comment: haha, I was so wrong, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong, the surround plugin has already been successfully installed. I should read the plugin manual carefully.

`cs"'` means "change `"Hello World"` into `'Hello World'`" not "change `Hello World` into `"Hello World"`".